# Need help configuring jQWidgets grid

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, import-from-excel

I have tried to create table that will use mySQL table to find values. Also it should filter rows by given results. For example I have **Name, Surname, Nationality, Age**. I need to search for all results with **Name** John, **Age** 22 and 23. In other words something similar to Pivot Tables of Excel. I have a lot of data in my table and would like to export it from Excel to for example .xml and import it to .sql database.

I have found plugin called  [jqxgrid](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/phpintegration/php-server-side-grid-filtering.htm)
 but cant get it to work properly. Here is my site: http://table.co.nf/
I have made database and connected it in the file `"/connect.php"` and `"/data.php"` but my `"/index.html"` doesn't display anything. 
Can anybody  help me?

Comment: you have forgot to include jquery to your paga

Comment: Hey, jquery is located in the folder called "jqwidgets". In index.html "<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is not defined. That is at least what the Google Chrome Debugger displays in its Console. I suggest you to check whether the reference to jQuery Framework on you page is correct.